# python pyramid server sent event returns error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, pyramid

I created a simple sse event with pyramid:

But from client side i only get an error response trying to receive the events.

```
def message_generator():
    for i in range(100):
        print("Sending message:" + str(i))
        yield "data: %s\n\n" % json.dumps({'message': str(i)})
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10))

@view_config(route_name='ssetest')
def events(request):
    Logger.warn("ssetest")
    headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream'),
               ('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')]
    response = Response(headerlist=headers)
    response.app_iter = message_generator()
    return response
```

client:

Javascript client side - creating new Eventsource with my pyramid url

```
var eventSource = new EventSource("myurl" + "/" + ssetest);
eventSource.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    targetContainer.innerHTML = e.data;
};
eventSource.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
};

eventSource.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}, false);
```

And i will get this error from EventSource but i could not understand whats going wrong.

```
{
    "returnValue": true,
    "timeStamp": 1564393825572,
    "eventPhase": 2,
    "target": {
        "readyState": 2,
        "onopen": null,
        "url": "myurl/ssetest",
        "withCredentials": false,
        "URL": "myurl/ssetest"
    },
    "defaultPrevented": false,
    "srcElement": {
        "readyState": 2,
        "onopen": null,
        "url": "myurl/ssetest",
        "withCredentials": false,
        "URL": "myurl/ssetest"
    },
    "type": "error",
    "cancelable": false,
    "currentTarget": {
        "readyState": 2,
        "onopen": null,
        "url": "myurl/ssetest",
        "withCredentials": false,
        "URL": "myurl/ssetest"
    },
    "bubbles": false,
    "cancelBubble": false
}
```

Is there anything missing ?

Also i dont find any other example with pyramid how to create a sse event :/
So if you have good examples please help me with them

Regards
Fabian

Comment: Possible examples in [pyramid_debugtoolbar](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_debugtoolbar/search?q=sse&unscoped_q=sse).

Comment: thanks @StevePiercy but dosnt helped me at all ._.